# how to play video in ipad web app

Tags: html, ipad, video

I am playing video in ipad but does not get play,i am using the following code.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <meta charset=”utf-8″>
  <meta name=”apple-mobile-web-app-capable” content=”yes” />
  <title>My Video</title>
  <link rel=”apple-touch-icon” href=”icon.png” />
  <style>
  body {margin:0;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <video width=”1024″ height=”750″ controls=”true”>
  <source src=”videos/test.m4v” />
  </video>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* Replace `”` with `"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>iOS only supports MP4, MOV, M4V format to be played natively. To make your MKV video plays in iPad, convert to a supported format.</s>

Replacing `”` with `"` to make syntax valid.